# Ionic/Cordova gives white screen with "internal server error"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created an Ionic app which uses Cordova. On Android and in the webbrowser it runs fine. However when running from XCode I get a blank screen with "Internal Server Error".

There are no messages in the error console about what could possibly be wrong.

When Googling on `cordova white screen "internal server error` almost any hit is about the server giving a 500 error. Which is here not the case.

I am wondering if anyone has experienced such same behaviour or what might cause this error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the white page was triggered when pgAdmin was running. When pgAdmin was shut down it worked without problems.

My guess is that the iOS emulator searched for the Ionic app on the same port as pgAdmin was running.